# Why does my mirror modifier work like this?

Tags: modifiers, mirror-modifier

I don't understand why mirror modifier rotate my model.
How i can fix that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello try to apply the rotation in Object mode (Ctrl A)

Comment: Yes, it helped, thanks

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

The orientation of your object is not correct, to fix that, apply the rotation in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)